# PHP stdClass issue

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I try to create an generic object which needs to be structuered like this:

```
[Content] => stdClass Object
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Value] => STRING
                    )

            )
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Value] => ANOTHER STRING
                    )
            )
    )
```

This is my code:

```
$content = new stdClass();
$data = file('filname.csv');

foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    $content->item->Value = $val;
}
```

This overwrites itself each time the loop iterates. By defining `item` as an array like this:

```
$content->item = array();
...
$content->item[]->Value = $val;
```

...the result is also not the estimated.

Comment: You can't have 2 properties with the same name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwritting data each time even using array. You should create temporary object for storing value and then put them to `item` array.

```
$content = new \stdClass();
$content->item = array();

foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    $itemVal = new \stdClass();
    $itemVal->Value = $val;
    $content->item[] = $itemVal;
}
```